# How to copy the values from the same column into the next columns? Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, paste

I am trying to copy the values from the same range (G8:G1000), and then paste those values to the next column (H8:H1000). However, I then want to copy that same range (G8:G1000) again, but then paste the values into I8:I1000, and do that at least 100 times. Essentially, there is a formula in column G that is producing randomized values, and I want to copy those unique values into all of the columns following column G. I believe I will need some sort of For Next loop, where it keeps selecting the values from G column, and then pasting them to the next column after the previously pasted into column, but I have very little VBA knowledge to figure this out. Does anyone have a potential solution for this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generate Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub generateColumns()
    
    Const rgAddress As String = "G8:G1000"
    Const cCount As Long = 100
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range(rgAddress)
    'rg.Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To cCount
        rg.Offset(, c).Value = rg.Value
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Beautiful, that did the trick! Thank you so much!